# IntegrityError: datatype mismatch in Python using praw

Tags: python, sqlite, praw

I am trying to write a reddit bot that takes the word "fuck" and see how many people say that on reddit. Here is the code:

```
import praw
import time
import re
import sqlite3

username = "LewisTheRobot"
password = "lewismenelaws"

conn = sqlite3.connect('reddit')
c = conn.cursor()
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "Reddit bot")

word_to_match = [r'\bfuck\b', r'\bfucking\b', r'\bfucks\b']

storage = []

r.login(username, password)

def run_bot():
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit("all")
    print("Grabbing subreddit!")
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=200)
    print("Grabbing comments!")
    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower()
        isMatch = any(re.search(string, comment_text) for string in word_to_match)
        if comment.id not in storage and isMatch and comment.author not in storage:
            print("We have found a fuck boy. Storing username: " + str(comment.author) + "into database.")
            storage.append(comment.author)
            c.execute("INSERT INTO users (id, Username, subreddit, comment) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (str(comment.id), str(comment.author), str(comment.subreddit), str(comment.body)))
            conn.commit()

    print("There are currently " + str(len(storage)) + " fuck boys on reddit at the moment.")



while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Whenever I run the bot it crashes whenever it finds a match and gives me this error.[image]

From what I understand it means that something in the database isnt the right datatype to be inserted into my database. I am pretty sure it is the `str(comment.body)` section of the SQL setting. My SQLITE database has the comment field as a text field. Thanks for the help.

Here are the database credentials shown in DB Browser.
[image]

Comment: Please include the SQL statements that define the database schema i.e. the ones beginning with `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @DanD. I am using DB Browser so I am unsure how to show the CREATE statement but I will show the table. edited OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `IntegrityError` results from the insert statement using `str(comment.id)` as `ID` which is a string and not a integer as the schema requires.

But as that didn't work. As `comment.id` is as you give `cogqssp`, you'll need to change your schema. The field `ID` to be of type `TEXT`. And then your original code will work.

Comment: Gave this a try and get an error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cogqssp'

Comment: This answer is correct , IntegrityError has to main reason : 1 - The one describe here (not respecting type ) 2 - Not unique records

Answer (score 1):

Alright figured it out. My datatype for the ID field was an integer however reddit's ID for comments. example: "cogr0o4". So I changed that to the datatype "TEXT" and made sql statement convert it into a string.